# Convergence of a random created series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random

We know that:

1. $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \infty$
2. $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n} < \infty$

Both are easy to show. In the first case we can use the criterion based on integrating the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and the convergence of the second series can be settle with the Dirichlet's criterion.
Let's imagine a random series:
$$\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_n}{n},$$
where $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = -1$.
$P(\lambda = 1) = P(\lambda = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$.
When the series will converge?

Comment: I guess that it converges...but I don't know why ;)

Comment: [This section on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Random_harmonic_series) might be interesting and relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the random variables $\lambda_n$ are independent and take the values $1$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$ each then $\sum \lambda_na_n$ converges almost surely if and only if $\sum a_n^{2}$ is finite. In particular this holds for $a_n=1/n$. However the series may not converge almost surely if independence is dropped: if all the $\lambda_n$ are equal then the series diverges almost surely.

Comment: Kolomogorov's three series theorem gives a proof of the claim I have made in my answer.

Comment: @Did Thanks for editing and removing the obvious error I had made.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to prove your claim using Kolomogorov's theorem